# Select statement to get specify date in string

Tags: sql, oracle, select

With a table like this:

```
article_tbl
 ID          varchar2(500) 
 REASON      varchar2(500)
 DESCRIPTION varchar2(500)
```

I need to get the date value from `REASON`

The date position can vary in the string depending on the description.

For example:

```
ID |DESCRIPTION | REASON                                                                 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |'DELETED'   |'THIS MESSAGE HAS BEEN DELETED ON 25/05/2018. PLEASE CHECK IN ARCHIVE.' |
2  |'AUTOREPLY' |'THIS WAS AUTOREPLY ON 25/05/2018.'                                     |
3  |'FORWARDED' |'THIS MESSAGE WAS FORWARDED ON 25/05/2015.MAILGROUP abc@outlook.com.'   |
4  |'SENT'      |'THIS MESSAGE WAS SENT TO SPECIFIC GROUP ON 25/05/2018'                 |
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well and assuming that all the values of `reason` are in one of the formats you listed, with correct dates, you can use:

```
select regexp_substr(reason, '[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}')
from article_tbl
```

This simply gets a string in the format `xx/xx/xxxx` where `x` is a digit; please notice that this way, even something like `99/45/8123` will be extracted.